# How to find admin console in Apache Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, server

I have always used WebSphere, where we can set data source and have buses and queues. How to find those features in Apache Tomcat, if possible?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491905/how-do-i-use-apache-tomcat-7-built-in-host-manager-gui

Comment: Worst ever title to describe the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat is a lightweight servlet server.
In order to add some of JEE features like JMS provider, you have to integrate a third party solution like **ActiveMQ** and declare your resources (datasources, queues or topics) in context.xml file like this :

```
<Resource name="jms/ConnectionFactory" auth="Container"
            type="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"/>
```

you can also use TomEE, which is a tomcat with JEE features. I think it's more suitable for you.

Hope it helped

Comment: how does this answer relate to the question?

Comment: If you have read the whole question, you would have seen that the answer is a solution. You must read the description and not just the title ! It's abvious !

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat is not a full-blown application server.

You can deploy / undeploy applications via tomcat.url:8080/manager

`manager` itself is a webapplication which ships with default installation.

To access it you will need to modify some config files. A complete guide for this can be found [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you are down to manually editing xml files.

If you considering switching to Apache Tomcat, try [WebSphere Liberty Profile](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/). It is as lightweight as Tomcat, but full Java EE 7 compatible, and have nice configuration editor in Eclipse provided by WebSphere Developer Tools plugin, so no looking for and typing xml configs.