# Why is Tomcat behaviour different in two pcs?

Tags: tomcat7

I did the same install in 2 pcs, both have the default tomcat-users.xml , one (with administrator rights) doesn't ask for password/user when trying to access localhost:8080, the other one (without administrator rights) asks for a username and password.

Why does that happens? Should I config manually the tomcat-users.xml with administrator role?

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this kind of behaviour but when I installed it, it didn't have any default user. I added user with required permissions. For adding new user you can follow these

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access

Or these

[How do I use Apache tomcat 7 built in Host Manager gui?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491905/how-do-i-use-apache-tomcat-7-built-in-host-manager-gui)

Instructions.

Comment: I don't have any default user, for some reason in one pc it isn't prompting anything and just works fine.

Comment: Are you using it alone or with a 3rd party software like net beans?

Comment: Alone, I didn't test it with eclipse (which is what I need)

Comment: Usually when we accessing localhost:8080 then we don't need any kind of permissions. We need them when we open application manager.

Comment: So, do I need to gran administrator permissions to the app?

Comment: Can you upload screenshot of window which asks for password?

Comment: Please clear one thing, Windows asks for administrator username and password or browser asks for username and password?

Comment: It's the browser when trying to access localhost:8080

Comment: Then add a user in tomcat-users.xml with required permissions and use it.

Comment: Thanks, I will try tomorrow.