# Access denied (error 403) to Tomcat 8 Manager on CentOS 7 without prompting for login/password

Tags: java, linux, apache, tomcat

I have set-up a CentOS 7 VPS with Tomcat 8 to serve my applications to my institute, following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-centos-7). I can access the Tomcat server usual page but not the App Manager. I believe I well configured the `tomcat-users.xml`, but I have no prompt for a login and password and it keeps telling me "403 Access denied". 
I already configured tomcat 8 but on an Ubuntu Server more than one year ago, and it worked out of the box.
There is probably something I missed .... but I can't see what it is.

Here is a copy of my `tomcat-users.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <user username="tomcat-xxxxxxx" password="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" roles="manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: any progress ? I have same problem

Comment: Sorry to be so late in my answer. No .... no progress. I reinstalled my test server few days ago, and I still have the same issue with Tomcat 8.5 ... really strange ...

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue,
Env: centos 6 64
Tomcat 8.5.23

Solution has been found here:
[403 Access Denied on Tomcat 8 Manager App without prompting for user/password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551166/403-access-denied-on-tomcat-8-manager-app-without-prompting-for-user-password)

Find the CATALINA_HOME/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml file and add the comment markers around the Valve.

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
<!--
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
-->
</Context>
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation puts both `manager-gui` and `admin-gui` as the roles the user is supposed to have. Try declaring the `admin-gui` role and adding it to the tomcat user you have there.

Comment: Thanks, Mike, for your help. I added the "admin-gui" but it didn't work, still no access. I am wondering if Tomcat read the file finally ....