# Tomcat 8.5 - 403 Access Denied

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu-16.04

I've created a virtual machine with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and, following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04), I've installed [Tomcat 8.5](http://192.168.1.124:8080/docs/index.html) and configured as follows:

**/opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager/META-INF/context.xml**:

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true">
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="192\.168\.1\.124|127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />    
</Context>
<!-- my local ip is 192.168.1.124 so I've added it -->
```

**/opt/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml**

```
<role rolename="manager-gui" />
<role rolename="admin-gui" />
<user username="myuser" password="MyPass123#" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui" />
```

No other configuration files has been modified.

The problem comes out when I try to access to the manager interface from my browser, it doesn't ask me any kind of credentials and throws me a 403 (Access Denied) error.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551166/403-access-denied-on-tomcat-8-manager-app-without-prompting-for-user-password

Answer (score 4):

This is worked for me. Please check
Find the `CATALINA_HOME/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml` file and add the comment markers around the Valve.

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
<!--
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
-->
</Context>
```

[Tomcat8 Documentation.](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access)